# Laravel roles middleware role or role instead role and role

Tags: laravel

By using this https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-roles package I am using roles for middlewares.

Is there a way to use role or role instead of role and role in example:

```
$this->middleware('auth');
$this->middleware(['role:basic', 'role:admin']);
```

The only way I can see is that to make permissions like:

```
canUseIndexMethodInTestController
canUseShowMethodInTestController
```

And then assing permissions to both roles.

Is there already made way for role or role, or not?

Comment: does it work like `$this->middleware(['role:basic|admin']);`

Comment: yes it does! didnt even think to do that

Comment: Adding it as an answer then :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like `$this->middleware(['role:basic|admin']);`

This works for [this package](https://github.com/santigarcor/laratrust) too.